# Htaccess file EerrorDocument doesn't redirect to custom error page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I have an `.htaccess` file on my website where I redirect the error pages to a custom `error.php` page.
The code I used, worked on localhost but now It's on the live site, the error page like 404 is not redirecting.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is my `.htaccess` code

```
# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# clean url
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# deny access to file types
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# error pages
ErrorDocument 401 /httpdocs/pages/error.php
ErrorDocument 402 /httpdocs/pages/error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /httpdocs/pages/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /httpdocs/pages/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /httpdocs/pages/error.php
```

I did try differtent paths to the file (with or withoud httpdocs) but that didnt work

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, could you please do mention what are sample urls: **from** where you want to redirect/rewrite **to** which url?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Just when a file is not found etc. so when you type www.domain.com/sjkfhahskj , you'll be redirected to the error page. I handle the error via php